# Using Algolia react-instantsearch with react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, algolia, react-instantsearch

I'm trying to get the new Algolia [react-instantsearch](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/react/) component using react-native.

I've been following the [guide](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/react/guide/React_native.html) and I'm completely stuck.

Basically, anytime I try to add my `<SearchBox />` component inside the `<InstantSearch />` component, my app dies with a **Expected a component class, got [object Object]**.

As far as I can tell, I'm wiring up `<SearchBox />` to the `connectSearchBox` connector so I'm not sure what's going on.

Code (I *do* have real values for appId, apiKey, & index):

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ListView,
  TextInput,
  Image,
} from 'react-native';
import {InstantSearch} from 'react-instantsearch/native';
import {connectSearchBox} from 'react-instantsearch/connectors';
import * as Styles from '../../styles/';

const SearchBox = connectSearchBox(({currentRefinement, refine}) =>
  <TextInput
    style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
    onChangeText={(text) => refine(text)}
    value={currentRefinement}
  />);

export default class InfiniteSearch extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
              <InstantSearch
                className="container-fluid"
                appId="appId"
                apiKey="apiKey"
                indexName="indexName"
              >
                <SearchBox />
              </InstantSearch>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      padding: 10,
    },
});
```

Comment: It definitely matches up with the guide from what I see...where does it say the error is?

Comment: @MattAft The stack trace doesn't point to anything specific in my code. Starts with `<unknown>` -> `createInternalComponent` -> `instantiateReactComponent` -> `peformInitialMount` but then goes on for pages & pages of internal React stuff.

Comment: It's definitely caused by the `<SearchBox />` component inside `<InstantSearch>` though. If I remove that, no errors.

Comment: We are working on a patch. https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch.js/pull/1729

Comment: @bobylito Thanks for the info. I've started watching that PR so I can grab the update when it's merged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is now solved in 2.0.1: https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch.js/blob/e15d37362fcd1eb60b5476307160062321983f09/CHANGELOG.md#201-2016-12-15

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the TextInput in the SearchBox:

```
const SearchBox = connectSearchBox(({currentRefinement, refine}) => (
  <TextInput
    style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
    onChangeText={(text) => refine(text)}
    value={currentRefinement}
  />
));
```