# React Native Algolia Instantsearch Expected a component class, got [object Object]

Tags: react-native, algolia

When I add the following code that appears on Algolia React Native documentation to `index.android.js` on a new and clean react native project. I get this error:

> "Expected a component class, got [object Object].

This is the code and is the same one shown on the Algolia React Native guide that you can find [here](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/react/guide/React_native.html)

```react
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ListView,
  TextInput,
  Image,
} from 'react-native';
import {InstantSearch} from 'react-instantsearch/native';
import {connectSearchBox, connectInfiniteHits} from 'react-instantsearch/connectors';

export default InfiniteSearch = () =>
  <View style={styles.maincontainer}>
    <InstantSearch
      className="container-fluid"
      appId="appId"
      apiKey="apiKey"
      indexName="indexName"
    >
      <SearchBox/>
      <Hits/>
    </InstantSearch>
  </View>;

const SearchBox = connectSearchBox(({currentRefinement, refine}) =>
  <TextInput
    style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
    onChangeText={(text) => refine(text)}
    value={currentRefinement}
  />
);

const Hits = connectInfiniteHits(React.createClass({
  onEndReached: function () {
    if (this.props.hasMore) {
      this.props.refine();
    }
  },

  render: function () {
    const dataSource = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    const hits = this.props.hits.length > 0 ?
      <View style={styles.maincontainer}>
        <ListView
        style={styles.list}
        dataSource={dataSource.cloneWithRows(this.props.hits)}
        renderRow={this._renderRow}
        onEndReached={this.onEndReached}/>
      </View> :
      null;

    return hits;
  },

  _renderRow: function (hit) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.item}>
        <Image
          style={{height: 100, width: 100}}
          source={{uri: hit.image}}
        />
        <Text>{hit.name}</Text>
      </View> );
    },
  }));

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  maincontainer: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 20,
    paddingBottom: 10,
    flexDirection: 'column',
  },
  list: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
  },
  item: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'white'
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('InfiniteSearch', () => InfiniteSearch);
```

Comment: Can you maybe show us the complete error trace? Maybe the line where it originates could be helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Algolia react-instantsearch with react-native](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41064940/using-algolia-react-instantsearch-with-react-native)